# SVG as product placeholder image

Tags: magento2.4.4, svg, placeholder-image

I manually uploaded svg to media subfolder (pub/media/catalog/product/placeholder/default) and edited in table core_config_data path catalog/placeholder/image_placeholder to reflect file name change (i.e. default/logo.svg)
All is fine with exception of changed mime type as svg is served as html. I did similar change of theme's logo image and file is served as svg.
How to change/force mime type for product placeholder images?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to exclude svg from nginx image_filter module (in default nginx magento config):

```
#  location ~* ^/media/catalog/.* {
   location ~* ^/media/catalog/.+(?<!\.svg)$ {

       set $width "-";
       set $height "-";
       if ($arg_width != '') {
           set $width $arg_width;
       }
       if ($arg_height != '') {
           set $height $arg_height;
       }
       image_filter resize $width $height;
       image_filter_jpeg_quality 90;
   }
```